# Mostrar lista de amigos con PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy creando una red social y me de detenido por un problema. Para ponerlos en contexto, ahora mismo estoy desarrollando un sistema de amigos dentro de la red social donde un usuario le envía una petición a otro usuario y el otro usuario tiene la opción de aceptarla o rechazarla. Ahora pues, haciendo el listado de amigos no he podido imprimir las 2 columnas (quién envió la solicitud y quien la recibe) Ahora mismo solo estoy imprimiendo 1. Debido a que no sé como puedo hacerlo en una consulta con inner join he intentado hacerla con left join, pero no sé como usarlo.

Esto es lo que llevo de código:

```php
<?php 
include '../db/db.php';
session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['username']; 
$resultId = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` = '$username'");
while($id = mysqli_fetch_array($resultId)) { $idUser = $id['id']; $usr = $id['username']; }

$q = "SELECT * FROM follows f INNER JOIN users u ON f.follower = u.id WHERE `following` = '$idUser' OR `follower` = '$idUser'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $q);

echo "Tus amigos: <br>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

   if($row['username'] == $usr) {
       $row['username'] = "";
   }else {
       echo "<p>". $row['username']. "</p>";
   }

}


?>
```

Esta es la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si lo que quieres es una consulta sobre la tabla de `users` y `follows` (Aunque... ¿es ésta la tabla que guarda las peticiones?), convendría ver la estructura de las tablas que intervienen y las relaciones entre ellas. Sin eso es difícil ayudar

Comment: Hola @VFG, lo que necesito es que exista una relación entre la tabla users y follows para obtener los usernames de estos, porque en la tabla de amigos guardo los id de los usuarios que son amigos. Además, no sé como mostrar la lista de amigos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seguimos sin ver la estructura de las tablas. Muestras una que supongo que es `follows`, pero no la de `users`.
Lo normal es que los seguidores del usuario `manuelperez` se tome como...

```
SELECT seguidores.follower as id_seguidor, 
    us_seguidores.username AS nombre_seguidor
FROM follows seguidores 
    JOIN users us_seguidores ON seguidores.follower=us_seguidores.id 
    JOIN users us_seguido ON seguidores.following = us_seguido.id 
WHERE 1
    AND us_seguido.username = 'manuelperez' 
    AND seguidores.status = 'Friends'
```

Se entiende que `status` define si son realmente amigos o no, y que esta relación es unidireccional (así que si dos se siguen mutuamente habría dos líneas)

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Muy bien. Me alegro si te ha ayudado. Pero si es una respuesta válida o correcta, podrías marcarla como "Aceptada", ¿verdad?